# Draw a trend line using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, trendline

I used ggplot2 to draw a trend line based on my data.

Below is something I've done using spreadsheet.

But I only want to show the trend line (black line as shown in upper plot) rather than all dots as number of observation is > 20,000.

So I tried to do the same thing using ggplot2.

```
fig_a <- ggplot(df1, aes(data_x, data_y ))
fig_a + stat_smooth(method=lm)
fig_a + stat_smooth(method=gam)
```

Apparently it does not work well, anyone can help?

Why it gives so many lines rather than single trend line?

Comment: your y variable appears to be a factor

Comment: How can I correct it?

Answer (score 53):

You can do the following. Add `+ geom_smooth(method = "lm")` to your ggplot script.

**Example using built-in data**

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

Comment: ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")   it does not work. many lines appeared as well.

Comment: Could you try to insert your variables in the line of code shown above?

Comment: The code works fine here. Maybe try to re-install the library for ggplot2; otherwise, you could update your version of R (if not using the most recent). Not sure, but could work.

Comment: right, probably because I have > 20,000 data point, I do not know, but I am using updated version. Thank you.

Comment: @Sakura: I confirm that milan's code is working for me. Just a little tip, if you "only want to show the trend line" (as you asked), omit geom_point() in milan's code. Thus resulting in ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_smooth(method = "lm")

Comment: @milan  Thanks for your help, but sorry the code does not work on my case, I do not know why, so would you mind I delete my question? Before this, would you mind deleting the answer, please?