# Compute trend of moisture index time series in different subperiods

Tags: r, time-series, timeserieschart, trendline

[desired_output_sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ILik.png)
I have following data:

```
#1. dates of 15 day frequency: 
dates = seq(as.Date("2016-09-01"), as.Date("2020-07-30"), by=15) #96 times observation  

#2. water content in crops corresponding to the times given.  
water <- c(0.5702722, 0.5631781, 0.5560839, 0.5555985, 0.5519783, 0.5463459, 
0.5511598, 0.546652, 0.5361545, 0.530012, 0.5360571, 0.5396569, 
0.5683526, 0.6031535, 0.6417821, 0.671358, 0.7015542, 0.7177007, 
0.7103561, 0.7036985, 0.6958607, 0.6775161, 0.6545367, 0.6380155, 
0.6113306, 0.5846186, 0.5561815, 0.5251135, 0.5085149, 0.495352, 
0.485819, 0.4730029, 0.4686458, 0.4616468, 0.4613918, 0.4615532, 
0.4827496, 0.5149105, 0.5447824, 0.5776764, 0.6090217, 0.6297454, 
0.6399422, 0.6428941, 0.6586344, 0.6507473, 0.6290631, 0.6011123, 
0.5744375, 0.5313527, 0.5008027, 0.4770338, 0.4564025, 0.4464508, 
0.4309046, 0.4351668, 0.4490393, 0.4701232, 0.4911582, 0.5162941, 
0.5490387, 0.5737573, 0.6031149, 0.6400073, 0.6770058, 0.7048311, 
0.7255012, 0.739107, 0.7338938, 0.7265202, 0.6940718, 0.6757214, 
0.6460862, 0.6163091, 0.5743775, 0.5450822, 0.5057753, 0.4715266, 
0.4469859, 0.4303232, 0.4187793, 0.4119401, 0.4201316, 0.426369, 
0.4419331, 0.4757525, 0.5070846, 0.5248457, 0.5607567, 0.5859825, 
0.6107531, 0.6201754, 0.6356589, 0.6336177, 0.6275579, 0.6214981)
```

I want to compute trend of the water content or moisture data corresponding to different subperiods. Lets say: one trend from 2016 - 09-01 to 2019-11-30.
and other trend from 2019-12-15 to the last date (in this case 2020-07-27).

And I want to make a plot like the one attached.
Appreciate your help. Can be in R or in python.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a trend line, you can look on this tutorial
https://www.statology.org/ggplot-trendline/

Or on this stackoverflow question
[Draw a trend line using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412817/draw-a-trend-line-using-ggplot)

To split your dataset in two groups you simply need to do something like this (in R).

```
data <- data.frame(dates, water)
#This neat trick allows you to turn a logical value into a number
data$group <- 1 + (data$dates > "2019-11-30")
old <- subset(data,group == 1)
new <- subset(data,group == 2)
```

For the plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(old,aes(x = dates, y = water)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", col = "blue") + 
  geom_point()
ggplot(new,aes(x = dates, y = water)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red") + 
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. Create a grouping variable by dates, coerce it to factor and `geom_smooth` will draw the two regression lines.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(ggpubr)
})

df1 <- data.frame(dates, water)

breakpoint <- as.Date("2019-11-30")
df1$group <- factor(df1$dates > breakpoint, labels = c("before", "after"))

ggplot(df1, aes(dates, water, colour = group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = 'white') +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = lm) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = breakpoint, linetype = "dotdash", linewidth = 1) +
  stat_cor(label.y = c(0.43, 0.38), show.legend = FALSE) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.y = c(0.45, 0.4), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(before = 'red', after = 'blue')) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 15)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Rui. How do I compute slope per groups, R2 and p value and plot them in the graph (as in the sample output)?

Comment: @kl40 There's a font artifact where there should be a times sign. I have tried to correct it but haven't succeeded yet. I will come back to this, eventually posting a solution. R 4.2.1 on Windows 11.

Comment: Hi @Rui, how do I put intercept, slope, R2 and p-value in plot instead of the equation? thanks

Comment: @kl40 But that's what is already there, the intercept and slope *are* the equation's coefficients. And the R2 and p-value are below. Can you make your question more clear, please?

Comment: what I mean is something like: intercept(c) = xxx, slope(m) = yyy, Rsq = zzz, p = vvv.

Comment: Hi, I have a follow up on this: How can the date be separated into groups based on year, and plot linear trend line over year? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full-fledged example with added labels:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dates <-  seq(as.Date("2016-09-01"), as.Date("2020-07-30"), by=15)
wc <- as.numeric(strsplit("0.5702722 0.5631781 0.5560839 0.5555985 0.5519783 0.5463459 0.5511598 0.5466520 0.5361545 0.5300120 0.5360571 0.5396569 0.5683526 0.6031535 0.6417821 0.6713580 0.7015542 0.7177007 0.7103561 0.7036985 0.6958607 0.6775161 0.6545367 0.6380155 0.6113306 0.5846186 0.5561815 0.5251135 0.5085149 0.4953520 0.4858190 0.4730029 0.4686458 0.4616468 0.4613918 0.4615532 0.4827496 0.5149105 0.5447824 0.5776764 0.6090217 0.6297454 0.6399422 0.6428941 0.6586344 0.6507473 0.6290631 0.6011123 0.5744375 0.5313527 0.5008027 0.4770338 0.4564025 0.4464508 0.4309046 0.4351668 0.4490393 0.4701232 0.4911582 0.5162941 0.5490387 0.5737573 0.6031149 0.6400073 0.6770058 0.7048311 0.7255012 0.7391070 0.7338938 0.7265202 0.6940718 0.6757214 0.6460862 0.6163091 0.5743775 0.5450822 0.5057753 0.4715266 0.4469859 0.4303232 0.4187793 0.4119401 0.4201316 0.4263690 0.4419331 0.4757525 0.5070846 0.5248457 0.5607567 0.5859825 0.6107531 0.6201754 0.6356589 0.6336177 0.6275579 0.6214981", " |\\n")[[1]])

data <- data.frame(date=dates, water_content=wc) %>% 
    mutate(group = ifelse(date <= as.Date("2019-11-30"), "g1", "g2"))

# calculate linear regression and create labels
lmo <- data %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    summarise(res=list(stats::lm(water_content ~ date, data = cur_data()))) %>% 
    .$res
lab <- sapply(lmo, \(x) 
    paste("Slope=", signif(x$coef[[2]], 5),
        "\nAdj R2=", signif(summary(x)$adj.r.squared, 5),
        "\nP=", signif(summary(x)$coef[2,4], 5)))

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=date, y=water_content, col=group)) + 
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(geom="smooth", method="lm") +
    geom_text(aes(date, y, label=lab),
        data=data.frame(data %>% group_by(group) %>% 
                summarise(date=first(date)), y=Inf, lab=lab), 
        vjust=1, hjust=.2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. How can this be modified considering years as break points, let's say group into 16, 17, 18, 19 and 20, and plot linear trend line over each years? thank you.